# When clicking on Tile, I want the sharepointpage to be redirected to a new sharepointpage, which url comes from the Hyperlinkcolumn Lien. How?

Tags: json, sharepoint-online, pnp-js

I will start with the images:
First the view is the colored tiles. what I want is when I click on a Tile, it has to redirect our sharepoint online to page to another page. The Url comes from the column Lien.

This formated View is based on this list.
[Formated view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mth8r.png)

[SharepointList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnYwh.png)

This is my JSON CODE:

{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
"hideSelection": true,
"hideColumnHeader": true,
"rowFormatter": {
"elmType": "div",
"style": {
"display": "flex",
"float": "left",
"flex-wrap": "wrap",
"align-items": "stretch",
"flex-direction": "row",
"padding": "5px",
"margin": "10px",
"max-width": "500px",
"border-radius": "8px",
"box-shadow": "5px 5px 5px grey",
"background-color": "=if([$Couleur]=='Vert', '#E1F8D6',if([$Couleur]=='Rose','#FFECF7',if([$Couleur]=='Bleu','#EDDFFF','#FFDACA')))"
},
"children": [
{
"elmType": "div",
"style": {
"flex-grow": "1",
"display": "flex",
"flex-direction": "column",
"flex-wrap": "nowrap",
"align-items": "left",
"max-width": "500px",
"min-width": "450px",
"padding-left": "10px"
},
"children": [
{
"elmType": "img",
"style": {
"width": "50px",
"height": "50px",
"padding-top": "10px",
"cursor": "pointer",
"display": "=if([$Icone]=='','none','')"
},
"attributes": {
"src": "=getThumbnailImage([$Icone], 50, 50)"
}
},
{
"elmType": "a",
"attributes": {
"href": "[$Lien]",
"class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDark--hover"
},
"style": {
"display": "block",
"font-size": "18px",
"font-weight": "500",
"padding-bottom": "10px",
"padding-top": "10px",
"text-decoration": "none",
"cursor": "pointer"
},
"txtContent": "=[$Title]"
},
{
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
"font-size": "14px",
"text-align": "left",
"padding-bottom": "10px",
"cursor": "pointer"
},
"txtContent": "[$Description]"
},
{
"elmType": "span",
"attributes": {
"href": "[$Lien]",
"class": "ms-fontColor-red ms-fontColor-redDark--hover"
},
"style": {
"font-size": "14px",
"text-align": "right",
"font-weight": "800",
"padding-right": "10px",
"padding-bottom": "30px",
"cursor": "pointer"
},
"txtContent": "➔"
}
]
}
]
}
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Akhi Mohammad, The code I have provided is the full code I have.
As you can see the view is a formatted JSON view for Sharepoint online.

You can see the tiles are colored and there in I have an image, a title etc.

It's that tile, I try to understand how to work with "href" but i am not succeeding in it.